# Cannot edit a field on a query

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2010, jet

This is the first time I was not able to find an answer to my questions on this forum, so I decided to sign up and post it.

I am having problems being able to edit a field in a query. I have 2 tables I am pulling data from, but I need 2 sets of data from the second table, this year and last year (in quarters).  I need to be able to edit the selected column (i.e. select a person).

Members Table (Selected is a yes/no field with a default of No)

```
| ID | Name | Selected | Status |
|  1 | Bob  |    No    |    M   |
|  2 | Sam  |    No    |    M   |
```

StampDues Table

```
| ID | DuesYear | Q1_Date | Q2_Date | Q3_Date | Q4_Date |
|  1 |   2020   |  1/1/20 |  4/1/20 |  7/1/20 | 10/1/20 |
|  1 |   2021   |  1/2/21 |  2/1/21 |         |         |
|  2 |   2020   |  1/2/20 |  4/2/20 |  7/2/20 | 10/2/20 |
|  2 |   2021   |  1/2/21 |         |         |         |
```

I am looking for an aggregate of the current year and last year's dates, but then need to be able to 'select' a person.

```
|Selected|Name |Last_Q1|Last_Q2|Last_Q3|Last_Q4|This_Q1|This_Q2|This_Q3|This_Q4|
|    #   | Bob |1/1/20 |4/1/20 |7/1/20 |10/1/20|1/2/21 |2/1/21 |       |       |
|    #   | Sam |1/2/20 |4/2/20 |7/2/20 |10/2/20|1/2/21 |       |       |       |
```

I tried a join statement originally, but was unable to select people. I am using simpler code now, but am still not able to select a person.

```
SELECT
  Selected,
  Name,
  (SELECT Q1_Date FROM StampDues WHERE [Member ID] = Members.MemberID AND DuesYear = year(now)-1) AS [Last Q1],
  (SELECT Q2_Date FROM StampDues WHERE [Member ID] = Members.MemberID AND DuesYear = year(now)-1) AS [Last Q2],
  (SELECT Q3_Date FROM StampDues WHERE [Member ID] = Members.MemberID AND DuesYear = year(now)-1) AS [Last Q3],
  (SELECT Q4_Date FROM StampDues WHERE [Member ID] = Members.MemberID AND DuesYear = year(now)-1) AS [Last Q4],

  (SELECT Q1_Date FROM StampDues WHERE [Member ID] = Members.MemberID AND DuesYear = year(now)) AS [This Q1],
  (SELECT Q2_Date FROM StampDues WHERE [Member ID] = Members.MemberID AND DuesYear = year(now)) AS [This Q2],
  (SELECT Q3_Date FROM StampDues WHERE [Member ID] = Members.MemberID AND DuesYear = year(now)) AS [This Q3],
  (SELECT Q4_Date FROM StampDues WHERE [Member ID] = Members.MemberID AND DuesYear = year(now)) AS [This Q4]
FROM Members
  WHERE GetIsMemberStatus(Status) = True
  ORDER BY Name;
```

GetIsMemberStatus is a custom function I made that returns True or False. It does not seem to be the issue, as it is filtering the names properly.

Just as a note, I am using this query as the control source of a continuous subform.  I can get the subform to work properly with a huge number of dlookup fields for the dates, but this populates slowly.  I would prefer a SQL query as they seem to populate much faster.

Comment: Saving calculated data is usually unnecessary and risks data getting out of sync. No update will work that involves an aggregate query. If it can be calculated for update, should be able to calculate when needed. If you really must save, alternatives involve domain aggregate functions and/or VBA.

Comment: There are other reasons a query is rendered not updatable and ineligible for UPDATE action. You have field names in query that are not in your table structures. I assume the ID fields are actually named MemberID and Member ID. Advise not use spaces in field names.

Comment: I am confused by the calculated statement.  None of the values selected from the tables are calculated, they are all actual values.  I just need to see them all at the same time, and be able to 'select' a person.  From there some VBA code loops through the members table, and further processes the members with the selected field set to Yes.  I am also aware of the no space rule for field names, I just learned that after I made that table, and a lot of code to go with it.

Comment: Calculated or joins of tables, the point is your query is not editable and cannot be used in an UPDATE action. The "Selected" value can be calculated within the query when needed for display in query or report. Latest version of query shows calculated fields.

Comment: @dms292 Please check the answer and let me know it works or not. Best wishes :)

Answer (score 1):

To understand what you are dealing with, I would

1. Create one query for StampDues for last year - q_LastYearDues

```
SELECT [Member ID] as MemberID, Q1_Date as [Last Q1], Q2_Date as [Last Q2], Q3_Date as [Last Q3], Q4_Date as [Last Q4]
FROM StampDues WHERE DuesYear = year(now)-1
```

2. Create one query for StampDues for this year - q_ThisYearDues

```
SELECT [Member ID] as MemberID, Q1_Date as [This Q1], Q2_Date as [This Q2], Q3_Date as [This Q3], Q4_Date as [This Q4]
FROM StampDues WHERE DuesYear = year(now)
```

3. Create your main query

```
SELECT a.Selected, a.Name, b.[Last Q1], b.[Last Q2],b.[Last Q3],b.[Last Q4]
,c.[This Q1], c.[This Q2],c.[This Q3],c.[This Q4]
From Members a 
left join q_LastYearDues b on a.MemberID=b.MemberID
left join q_ThisYearDues c on a.MemberID=c.MemberID
```

This way you can run each query independently to figure out where your issue is - could be text values joining to an integer or something like that. The first 2 queries should be updatable.

Also ensure that primary keys are defined on tables as sometimes that can make a table readonly.

Comment: This seems promising.  Primary keys are defined an all tables.  If I only use the fist join, I get no errors, and the selected field is editable (also remove the select c.*).  When I add the second join, I get the error "Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression 'a.MemberID=b.MemberID left join q_ThisYearDues c on a.MemberID=c.MemberI'."  And yes, it is cutting off the last character of MemberID at the end.

Comment: That is strange. If you are running it in an MS Access query to test it out, that situation should never arise. I would isolate all 3 queries in their own queries with the final joining the 2 so you can clearly debug what's happening. Basically create a new query for each, ignore the add table dialog, go to SQL view and just paste the queries as I have them. I've modified them slightly in my answer to reflect your exact fields.

Comment: I did just that, I am testing them in queries first. q_LastYearDues &  q_ThisYearDues work individually.  They also work when joined in the third query individually (all references to the other query are removed).  If then are both in the query (copied form your text above) I get that strange error previously mentioned.

Comment: Would it make a difference if there is a possibility that a member does not have a record for last year?  A new member this year, would not have a record for last year.

Comment: I would try joining the 2 queries that run ok individually with members in design view. I can’t see why the main query would error out unless you are doing a summary on nulls. The 3rd query is not an aggregation. 
The only reason for the left join is because we assume that the member table contains all members from this year and last year.  
Old members might not have paid dues this year and new members this year didn’t pay dues last year. What you get will be all members filled in and sometimes for old member dues and sometimes for new member dues, you get nulls

Answer (score 0):

I think the only way you'll be able to get this to work is to do a Make-Table query (SELECT xxx INTO tempTable FROM xxx) into a temp table, and insert the boolean 'Selected' column as part of the query. You'd need to delete the temp table each time and recreate it with the Make-Table query.

Then you can bind the temp table to the continuous form. You'd either need code or SQL to get the data entered back into the db.

Answer (score 0):

From the sentence you said, "I am looking for an aggregate of the current year and last year's dates, but then need to be able to 'select' a person." what I have understood is that you want the `MemberID`. If it is like that, then I might have a solution for you.

**SQL**

```
DECLARE @MEMBER TABLE( ID INT, [NAME] VARCHAR(30),SELECTED BIT,[Status] VARCHAR(2));
DECLARE @StampDues TABLE( ID INT,DuesYear VARCHAR(10),Q1_Date DATE,Q2_Date DATE,Q3_Date DATE,Q4_Date DATE);
INSERT INTO @MEMBER VALUES(1,'Bob',0,'M');
INSERT INTO @MEMBER VALUES(2,'Sam',1,'M');

INSERT INTO @StampDues VALUES(1,'2020','1/1/20','4/1/20','7/1/20','10/1/20');
INSERT INTO @StampDues VALUES(1,'2021','1/2/21','2/1/21',null,null);
INSERT INTO @StampDues VALUES(2,'2020','1/2/20','4/2/20','7/2/20','10/2/20');
INSERT INTO @StampDues VALUES(2,'2021','1/2/21',null,null,null);

WITH summary AS (
Select s.*,m.NAME,m.SELECTED,
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY m.ID 
                                 ORDER BY s.DuesYear DESC) AS rn
FROM @MEMBER m
INNER JOIN @StampDues s ON  m.ID=s.ID
)
SELECT s.ID MEMBERID,s.NAME,s.SELECTED,s.Q1_Date Last_Q1,s.Q2_Date Last_Q2,
       s.Q3_Date Last_Q3,s.Q3_Date Last_Q4,
       s1.Q1_Date This_Q1,s1.Q2_Date This_Q2,
       s1.Q3_Date This_Q3,s1.Q3_Date This_Q4
FROM summary s
INNER JOIN summary s1 ON s1.rn=1 and s.rn=2 and s.ID=s1.ID
```

To Update on condition you can try like this after the end of `WITH summary AS(......)`=>

```
UPDATE @MEMBER SET SELECTED=1 WHERE ID IN
(SELECT s.ID MEMBERID
    --   ,s.NAME,s.SELECTED,s.Q1_Date Last_Q1,s.Q2_Date Last_Q2,
    --   s.Q3_Date Last_Q3,s.Q3_Date Last_Q4,
       --s1.Q1_Date This_Q1,s1.Q2_Date This_Q2,
    --   s1.Q3_Date This_Q3,s1.Q3_Date This_Q4
FROM summary s
INNER JOIN summary s1 ON s1.rn=1 and s.rn=2 and s.ID=s1.ID
WHERE s.SELECTED=0 --your condition
)
SELECT * FROM @MEMBER;--To Check the data is Updated
```

**NOTE:** Now, If you want update your `MEMBER` table you can use the `MEMBERID` and you also can manipulate the query as per your requirements. Please check the code and let me know. Query is written on SQL SERVER 16.

Comment: It will not work on `MS-Access` database.

Comment: ok. thank for correcting me @Harun24HR . But my code is in SQL Server. Best wishes .:)